# Python turtle game, making walls that aren't outside borders

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a game in Python turtle. I know that's not what it's made for, but I thought it would be fun. I have a "river" in my game that I don't want players be able to cross unless they cross the bridge, so I'm trying to make it so that they get set back to the start if they try to cross the river without using the bridge. I just don't know how to do this after multiple attempts.
Here is my code:

```
import turtle
import random
import time
wn = turtle.Screen()
layout = turtle.Turtle()
layout.speed(100)
layout.up()

wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")
def drawTree(t, sd):
for i in range(4):
    layout.down()
    t.forward(sd)
    t.right(90)
    layout.up()

def drawRiver():
for i in range(2):
    print(layout.pos()[0])
    print(layout.pos()[1])
    layout.color("darkblue")
    layout.fillcolor("blue")
    layout.begin_fill()
    layout.down()
    layout.forward(2000)
    layout.right(90)
    layout.forward(99)
    layout.right(90)
    layout.forward(4000)
    layout.end_fill()
    layout.up()

def tree(branchLen,layout):
if branchLen > 6:
    layout.down()
    layout.forward(branchLen)
    layout.right(20)
    tree(branchLen-6,layout)
    layout.left(40)
    tree(branchLen-6,layout)
    layout.right(20)
    layout.backward(branchLen)
    layout.up()

def main():
myWin = turtle.Screen()
layout.left(90)
layout.up()
layout.backward(100)
layout.down()
layout.color("brown")
tree(36,layout)
layout.right(90)
layout.up()


def drawBridge():
layout.goto(50, -120)
layout.down()
layout.color("rosybrown4")
layout.fillcolor("saddlebrown")
layout.begin_fill()
layout.forward(100)
layout.left(90)
layout.forward(150)
layout.left(90)
layout.forward(100)
layout.left(90)
layout.forward(150)
layout.left(90)
layout.up()
layout.end_fill()
layout.goto(150, -118)
layout.left(90)
for i in range(38):
    layout.pensize(.1)
    layout.down()
    layout.color("black")
    layout.forward(.1)
    layout.left(90)
    layout.forward(100)
    layout.left(90)
    layout.forward(.1)
    layout.left(90)
    layout.forward(100)
    layout.left(90)
    layout.up()
    layout.forward(4)
layout.up()
layout.right(90)

layout.goto(-799, 0)
drawRiver()
drawBridge()
# Tree locations
layout.goto(222, 198)
main()
layout.goto(-334, 155)
main()
layout.goto(132, 140)
main()
layout.goto(400, -200)
main()
layout.goto(50, -222)
main()
layout.goto(180, -122)
main()
layout.goto(-400, 400)
main()
layout.goto(-332, -332)
main()
layout.goto(-472, 400)
main()
layout.goto(-400, -380)
main()
layout.goto(-362,200)
main()
layout.goto(-222, 198)
main()
layout.goto(-750, -300)
main()
layout.goto(600, -467)
main()
layout.goto(100, 450)
main()
layout.goto(-100, 400)
main()
layout.goto(-600, 400)
main()
layout.goto(500, 123)
main()
layout.goto(700, 400)
main()
layout.goto(350, 350)
main()

layout.color("blue")
layout.goto(0, -50)
Player = turtle.Turtle()
Player.up()
Player.goto(0, -200)
Player.left(90)

def k1():
Player.forward(45)

def k2():
Player.left(30)

def k3():
Player.right(30)

def k4():
Player.back(45)

wn.onkey(k1, "Up")
wn.onkey(k2, "Left")
wn.onkey(k3, "Right")
wn.onkey(k4, "Down")

wn.listen()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a challenge to work with.

For this example, I've tossed your trees and bridge planks as they have no affect on the problem.  Since your river and bridge are rectangular, I've wrapped their drawing in a `begin_poly()` and `end_poly()` combination so that we have the bounding boxes of those rectangles.  Then, for the two movement commands (forward and backward) we test if the resulting movement puts us in the river, but not the bridge, and simply `goto()` the starting position if that's the case:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def inside(point, rectangle):
    x, y = point

    # not efficient, just a quick solution
    x1 = min(p[0] for p in rectangle)
    y1 = min(p[1] for p in rectangle)
    x2 = max(p[0] for p in rectangle)
    y2 = max(p[1] for p in rectangle)

    return x1 < x < x2 and y1 < y < y2

def not_safe(turtle):
    position = turtle.position()
    return inside(position, river) and not inside(position, bridge)

def drawRiver(turtle):
    turtle.color('darkblue', 'blue')

    turtle.goto(-WIDTH / 2, 0)

    turtle.begin_poly()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(WIDTH)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(WIDTH)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.end_poly()

    return turtle.get_poly()

def drawBridge(turtle):
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.goto(50, -120)
    turtle.color('rosybrown4', 'saddlebrown')

    turtle.begin_poly()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(150)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.end_poly()

    return turtle.get_poly()

wn = Screen()
wn.bgcolor('lightgreen')
WIDTH = wn.window_width()

layout = Turtle(visible=False)
layout.speed('fastest')
layout.penup()

river = drawRiver(layout)
bridge = drawBridge(layout)

player = Turtle('turtle')
player.penup()

player.goto(0, -200)
player.setheading(90)

def k1():
    player.forward(45)
    if not_safe(player):
        player.goto(0, -200)
        player.setheading(90)


def k2():
    player.back(45)
    if not_safe(player):
        player.goto(0, -200)
        player.setheading(90)

def k3():
    player.left(30)

def k4():
    player.right(30)

wn.onkey(k1, 'Up')
wn.onkey(k2, 'Down')
wn.onkey(k3, 'Left')
wn.onkey(k4, 'Right')

wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, but can you mix my code with yours, the whole code. It is really hard to combine them.